# Place marker on map using users address using javascript and cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps

I've been trying to create a simple android app using cordova where the user enters an address into a text box and the map will update itself with a marker on the map from the address that was inputted. I have managed to get the code to work to place a marker based on my current location as a 1st phase and have tried countless attempts to then use the address that is passed in but i am failing miserably - this is my 1st phase code, please be gentle as I am not a natural coder and javascript is not my thing:

```js
function updateMap(address) {
   var onSuccess = function (position) {
    var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
    div.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
    div.height = window.innerHeight * 0.8 - 40;
    var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);
    map.setVisible(false);
    var currentLocation = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    
    map.addMarker({
     'position': currentLocation,
     'title': "You are here!"
    }, function (marker) {
     marker.showInfoWindow();
    });
    map.setCenter(currentLocation);
    map.setZoom(15);
    map.refreshLayout();
    map.setVisible(true);
  
   };
   var onError = function(error) {
              alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
            };
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }
```

Any help you could offer up would be appreciated, I have tried reading the google geocoding api docs and to be honest dont really understand them. Be happy to be pointed in the right direction - is the google geocoding the right way to go?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to initialise the map first separately from navigator.geolocation, so you don't end up re-creating the map every time u track users location. For address you can use [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) or [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/)